# password protecting an EPIServer site

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, localhost, episerver

I have developed a EpiServer site and hosted that in my server machine IIS. Now I want to make the site password protected through IIS authentication mechanism. I have tried to set the basic authentication so that if user want to access that site he need to give the windows credential of that site. For the one time it works but after that it is not working. Please help me to set the authentication mechanism on IIS.

Comment: maybe ask it at serverfault.com..?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Authentication model (in IIS) you prefer and **disable anonymous access** to the site in IIS

You can also add a location element to web.config

```
<location path="">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

You can also set access rights in the tree view of the site

http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Martin-Helgesen/Dates/2010/11/Virtual-Roles-and-access-control-in-EPiServer/